# Vb.net Iterate over dictionary to refresh the listbox item property

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm trying to create a sorted dictionary `libraries` where it will be filled with a libraries full name and the acronym if the building name. However, I'm having issues accessing the data I created and printing it in the listbox. Getting the error `'Libraries' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.` I think this is due to a scope issue with the sub not being able to read into Main. Why is this? And how can I reach my dictionary to be able to print?

My error occurs in the `For Each` loop as it does not have access to `In Libraries`

```
public Class frmManager

Public Sub Main()

    Dim Libraries As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

    Libraries.Add("Zexrow Library", "ZRLB")
    Libraries.Add("Williams Memorial Library", "WML")
    Libraries.Add("Dervin Technical Repository", "DTR")

End Sub

Private Sub lstLibraries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstLibraries.SelectedIndexChanged

    lstLibraries.Items.Clear()

    For Each library In Libraries
        lstLibraries.Items.Add()
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Well, yeah, of course you are. You declared the `Libraries` inside the `Main` method so it only exists inside the `Main` method`. If you want to access a variable from multiple methods then it must be declared outside all of them.

Comment: So should I be declaring it outside, but adding and iterating within my subs?

Comment: When I try that and use `lstLibraries.Items.Add(library.ToString)` I do not get any errors, but no output in the list box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your libraries obect out of the MAIN sub (scope) and drop it in the FORM (scope)

```
public Class frmManager

Dim Libraries As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

Public Sub Main()

Libraries.Add("Zexrow Library", "ZRLB")
Libraries.Add("Williams Memorial Library", "WML")
Libraries.Add("Dervin Technical Repository", "DTR")

lstLibraries.Items.Clear()

For Each library In Libraries
  lstLibraries.Items.Add(library.Key)
Next

End Sub

End Class
```

**Edited**
Edited to ensure you load the listbox in the Sub Main event/procedure

Comment: When I do that and use `lstLibraries.Items.Add(library.ToString)` I do not get any errors, however 0 output in my list box. Why is that?

Comment: I have edit the answer to ensure you load the listbox in the sub main event/procedure rather than in the listbox selection changed event.

Comment: Ok thank you, still not getting any text displayed in the list box when I run the application for some reason when using `.Add(library.Key)`

Comment: You can try it with .Add(Library.Tostring()) as you had But I suspect it will display both the key and the value in that case. Do you have any other code which modifies the listbox? Did you take out the lstLibraries_SelectedIndexChanged event code?

Comment: Yeah my code is exactly as you have it. the `SelectedIndexChanged event` code is gone, and I tried both `Library.ToString()` and `library.Key.toString()` none of which had output.

Comment: That's strange, because the listbox is loaded in the same event procedure as the libraries are defined, so it should definitely show. Are you clearing/resetting Libraries object anywhere instead of lstLibraries object and therefore clearing the library before  loading anything into the listbox?

Comment: This is the first part of the application I started working on, so there is no other code besides what you posted.

Comment: Is this code for a windows form? If yes then it should reside in the form load event, not the Sub Main event

Comment: Ah yes, it's in a windows form. It works in the load event. Thank you!